# Питома форма до "Запорізька область" — Запоріжжя, Запоріжчина?

Tags: вибір-слова, власні-назви

Постійно стикаюся з суперечками стосовно використання слова *Запоріжжя* в сенсі *Запорізька область* або *територія навколо Запоріжжя*.

Сумніви мовців зрозумілі: назва міста Запоріжжя саме по собі несе сенс «територія, регіон», як-то *Поділля*, *Полісся*, *Прикарпаття*, *Забужжя*.
Таким чином, *Запоріжжя* (область) звучить так само, як *Запоріжжя* (місто).

З іншого боку, *Запоріжчина*, схоже, [не є занадто популярним](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&lr=-lang_ru), хоча і має декілька [вжитків](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82:%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), в тому числі і такі:

[image: Проєкт політичної партії ЄС]

---

Отже, запитання: який з варіантів *Запоріжжя, Запоріжчина* (або інший) є більш питомим з точки зору українського словотворення?

Comment: вся територія за [дніпровими порогами](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8) називається запоріжжя, `запоріжчина` — це вже незнання автора географії і спроба вжити це слово як нп. Львівщина, Полтавщина ітд.

Comment: хоча, з іншого боку... запоріжжя, в сенсі «за дніпровими порогами» набагато більша територія, ніж сьогоднішня запорізька область, так що ця назва має сенс, якщо мова йде про конкретно цю область, кордони якої утворені в 1990-х

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Коротко

- *Запоріжжя* це радше *гісторичний реґійон* або просто *назва міста*,
- називати *Запорізьку область* — *Запоріжчиною* можна, сам конструкт має вжиток, втч на державному рівнї, а етімолоґично і семантично — *питомий*.

## Довго

> <sub>Автор питання</sub>
>
> Сумніви мовців зрозумілі: назва міста *Запоріжжя* саме по собі несе сенс *територія, регіон*, як-то *Поділля, Полісся, Прикарпаття, Забужжя*.

Не буду вдавати ся в [гісторію назви міста](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B6%D1%8F#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0), але схожість проявяїть ся наростком [*-ьja*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-%D1%8Cja) чи [*-ьje*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-%D1%8Cje), що в більшостї випадків є для [збірних](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) або абстрактних іменників. В таких випадках зазвичай наводю такий приклад:

> однина *волос*, *корїнь* – множнина *волоси*, *коренї* – збірнина *волосся*, *корїння*

Тобто згадані вами приклади не просто теріторії, а з певними ознаками. Вікіпедія їх зазвичай позначаїть як *гісторіко-ґеоґрафичний та етнокултурний реґійон*, де, як не дивно, входить і [*Запоріжжє*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B6%D1%8F), що не обмежуїть ся межами областї, ба навіть не охопює повністю саму область:
[image: Історіко-ґеоґрафичний та етнокултурний реґіон Запоріжжя]

Можна також згадати подібні теріторіяльні іменники, але не як назви чогось: *узбережжя*, *бездоріжжя*, *зарубіжжя* ітд.

Тому якщо мова са́ме про *Запорізьку область*, то *Запоріжчина* будить ближче за декотрими ознаками:

- Наросток [*-ина*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-ina) дуже продуктивний, теж може в збірні іменники.
- Вже є подібні вжитки як *Київщина*, *Львівщина*, *Одещина*, *Житомирщина* ітд, що позначають таки *область*. І ті вжитки утворені з *прикметника* з основою на *-ськ-*, котре тут через асімілацію стає *-зьк-*. Такого не сказати про *Запоріжжя*, що утворене з приростка *за* і *іменника*.

Щодо питомостї, то оба наростки, очевидно, є питомі українській. Але ось зі вжитком *-ськ-* + *-ина* на позначення *земель* чи навіть країн, напевно написати не можу, але менї здаїться, що це відносно нове явище явище, бо в дуже старих назв не пригадую.

Схоже, так воно і є, натрапив на працю:

> <sub>доктор філолоґичних наук, професор [Петро Іванович Білоусенко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87): [*Формування словотвірної структурилокативних найменувань в історії української мови*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GZXJqXJO0PQJ:www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe%3FC21COM%3D2%26I21DBN%3DUJRN%26P21DBN%3DUJRN%26IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD%3D1%26Image_file_name%3DPDF/Vznu_fi_2016_2_50.pdf)</sub>
>
> Однак суфікс *-щина* не брав участі у творенні локативних назв у прасловʼянській мові, не трапляється він і в обстежених текстах української мови ХІ-ХІІІ ст. Проте цей формант успадкував від свого попередника семантику сукупності, яка прозирала в багатьох дериватах на *-ина* праслов’янської доби[див. 41 І, с. 121] та українській мові давньокиївського періоду.
>
> ---
>
> Просторових назв із цим формантом в обстежених пам’ятках української мови ХІ-ХІІІ ст. не виявлено, однак дещо пізніше згадана семантика сукупності стала підґрунтям для появи дериватів iз локативним значенням.
>
> Семантика збірності поступово закріпилася в нових дериватах. Найперше вона відчувається в багатьох утвореннях від посесивних прикметників за належністю земель, територій певним особам. [З. Т. Франко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) відзначала, що топоструктури з цим суфіксом в ХІV-ХV ст. „набули значення релятивної просторової абстракції, ставши формантом найменувань обʼєктів, які не були точно окреслені на терені, тобто земельних ділянок, володінь, ланів, нив, тощо. [...] Переважна більшість структур на *-щина* досить густою сіткою покриває територію Київщини, [...] звідки, слід гадати, ці структури і беруть свій родовід, далі ізоглосою проходять уздовж північного етнічного порубіжжя аж до Волині, ана південно-західному терені не зустрічаються зовсім. Експансія йшла, як видно, з центральних регіонів у південно-західному напрямі” [33, с. 47]. Перші деривати цього типу фіксуються, за нашими даними, у ХІV ст. — це, власне, переважно назви земельних володінь на різних територіях.
>
> ---
>
> Наведені факти підтверджують думку [Л. Т. Масенко](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) про те, що в ХVІ-ХVІІІ ст. в українській мові з’являються ойконіми на *-щина*, *-івщина*, переважно з посесивним значенням, в окремих випадках — з топографічним. Назви з цим формантом були відомі уже в топонімії попередньої епохи, але в староукраїнський період ХІV-ХV ст. до них належали виключно найменування земельних володінь, утворені від імен і прізвищ власників. У ХVІ–ХVІІІ ст. функція суфікса *-щина* в українській топонімії розширюється — він починає вживатись і для творення назв населених пунктів [див. 20, с. 647] і найменувань територій, які знаходяться під чиєюсь управою. Певне, існувала йсуспільна необхідність в однотипних іменуваннях окремих територіальних одиниць, адже саме в цей час збільшувалася кількість міст, містечок, за назвою яких почала іменуватися навколишня місцевість.

І тут загалом, гадаю, можна спинити ся. Підсумую:

- семантіка перенесла ся на місцину десь в 14–15 віках;
- десь з 16–18 віків так почали позначати і адміністратівні одиницї, чим і є *область*.

Тобто в підсумку є питомим і *адміністратівний поділ* можна позначати наростком *-ина*;

Сам [вжиток](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B6%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%22+site:*.gov.ua) є і на державних сайтах., втч від рекомендованим МОН-ом [підручника](//lib.imzo.gov.ua/wa-data/public/site/books2/pidruchnyky-11-klas-2019/23-ukrainska-mova-dlya-dlya-nacionalnyh-menshyn-11-klas/babych-ukr-mova-11kl-rum.pdf) [Надії Бабичи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) і:

> <sub>[Запорізька обласна прокуратура](//zap.gp.gov.ua/ua/news.html?_m=publications&_t=rec&id=274945)</sub>
>
> Тривалий час *Запоріжчина* залишається криміногенним регіоном…
>
> …виділила проблемні питання *Запоріжчини*, …

---

> <sub>Автор питання</sub>
>
> Таким чином, *Запоріжжя* (область) звучить так само, як *Запоріжжя* (місто).

Про всяк зазначу, що це цїлком звичне явище. Менї зараз складно згадати український приклад, але можна одразу згадати: *Алжір*, *Бразілія* ітд, що позначають країну і столицю, *Новий Йорк* — місто і державу; ітд.